# PHPUnit - Fatal error: Method PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError::__toString() must not throw an exception in... when a test class is empty?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have just started learning PHPUnit, when I create an empty class like this one:

```
<?php

namespace some\ns;

use some\ns\AClass;

/**
 * Test class for the some\ns\AClass class
 */
class AClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

}
```

When I run the test:

```
$ phpunit -c .
PHPUnit 4.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from path/to/phpunit.xml.dist

F

Time: 281 ms, Memory: 3.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) Warning

Fatal error: Method PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError::__toString() must not throw an exception in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php on line 0

Call Stack:
    0.0329     339512   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0330     339512   2. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
    0.1409     779176   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:605
    0.1409     779424   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:605
    0.1409     780048   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:138
    0.1410     780544   6. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:138
    0.2650    2779792   7. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:186
    0.2650    2780016   8. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:186
    0.2806    3526000   9. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printResult() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:429
    0.2806    3526360  10. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printResult() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:429
    0.2808    3529928  11. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printFailures() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php:177
    0.2808    3530160  12. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printFailures() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php:177
    0.2808    3530464  13. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefects() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php:288
    0.2808    3530464  14. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefects() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php:288
    0.2808    3530960  15. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefect() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php:233
    0.2808    3531192  16. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefect() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php:233
    0.2809    3532280  17. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefectTrace() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php:244
    0.2809    3532512  18. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefectTrace() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php:244
```

This exception is raised. For curiosity, could someone tell me why?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe due to the fact you do not have a test* method in the class?  The method names are used to show the tests executing.

Comment: @StevenScott I have added a `test*` method and a `dataProvider` method. now if I run the tests and they are are all successful and I don't get the exception I posted, but if at least a test fails I get the above exception again... What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved thanks to this answer of Sebastian Bergmann on GitHub:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1598#issuecomment-72880416

It appears that the autoloader specified with the `bootstrap` parameter of the PHPUnit config XML file must not throw any exception when a file of a class is not found.

This is also what PSR-4 specification states:

> Autoloader implementations MUST NOT throw exceptions, MUST NOT raise
>   errors of any level, and SHOULD NOT return a value.

I had to change the autoloader. Now it doesn't throw any kind of exceptions and everything works!

Any way, just to know, why in the error `PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError` there's no mention about the exception my autoloader used to throw?